# Guidelines for using [[likely]] / [[unlikely]] attributes in c++20

Tags: c++, attributes, c++20, micro-optimization, likely-unlikely

What is the general guideline for using the `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]` attributes in c++20, for the cases where we have only two possible branches of code execution? Is it advised to put `[[likely]]` or `[[unlikely]]` on just one branch of execution path or we should be putting one of it on one code branch and other one on the remaining branch. For example, should we be doing

```
if (condition) [[likely]]
{
}
else [[unlikely]]
{
}
```

or

```
if (condition) [[likely]]
{
}
else
{
}
```

when we know that the branch in if condition is more likely to get executed.

Comment: "*when we know that the branch in if condition is more likely to get executed.*" That alone isn't enough reason to use these attributes. You should only use them when you have a performance problem that you've tracked down to particular conditional branches. Preferably after assembly analysis suggests that it could perform better if you hinted things at the compiler. The proposal is clear about this: "The proposed attributes are not meant to be added to code **without measuring the impact to ensure they do not end up degrading performance.**"

Comment: I don't see a reason that a compiler should consider these two examples different. The tag does anyway only imply some "arbitrary" preference in likelihood above/below the other paths.

Comment: Might be interesting for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjPK3HKcouA and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ew3wt0g99kg

Comment: The number one guideline for using this kind of annotation is to measure the optimized performance difference.  If you don't measure the before and after, you don't know if you've improved things or made them worse.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for your comments. Curious to understand if adding this attribute is going to make things worse than not having them at all. For example cases where one code branch is going to be executed in all normal cases until something weird happens and for those cases say we just want to print the message. So we mark the normal case as likely branch.

Comment: @DineshMaurya: That's why you *don't use it* unless you have profiling data in hand that says that this specific condition may be a problem.